# Hide/show html content with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for javascript that will allow more HTML to appear on a website when a user clicks on an icon. I'm working on my first ever mobile design, and am building a prototype with html,css and javascript. Here is what I have so far: http://www.patthorntonfiles.com/snk_mobile

What I want to happen is when users click on the search icon at the top, a search box appears. I don't want the jquery accordion effect or something similar. I just want some HTML to appear and then disappear when a user clicks on the icon again or hits search.

Any recommendations for code or libraries for me to look at what be great. I don't need you to give me the code, but my Google searches aren't turning up exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Upgrade to the latest version of jQuery if you're starting a new project! 1.6.2 is old.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

jQuery's *hide()* and *show()* will do exactly that (they don't have any accordion effect, they just appear and dissapear with no ornaments).

```
$('#HtmlId').hide();
$('#HtmlId').show();
```

Additionally you get *toggle()*, to hide if shown and show if hidden:

```
$('#HtmlId').toggle();
```

---- Edit ----
After reading your comment, imagine you have the html:

```
<li><img id='hideShowIcon' src="patthorntonfiles.com/snk_mobile/search.gif"; width="50px'"/></li>
```

And the div to hide/show is:

```
<div id="search"> <gcse:search></gcse:search> </div>
```

Then you bind the click event to the image with the callback function performing the toggle:

```
$("#hideShowIcon").click(function() {
    $('#search').toggle();
});
```

----- Edit 2-----

I saw your site and you don't have a document ready function. Basically it should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#hideShowIcon").click(function() {
        $('#search').toggle();
  });
 });
```

If you don't add this, jQuery tries to bind the action to an element that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: The toggle sounds like exactly what I'm looking for. I'm a little slow today. Could you help point me in the right direction as to how I could use it with this code:

This is where my search icon is:

<li><img src="http://patthorntonfiles.com/snk_mobile/search.gif" width="50px'"/></li>


and then this is where the actual search box would appear:

 <div id="search">
  <gcse:search></gcse:search>
  </div>

Comment: Hey I edited my answer. Please note I added an ID field to the image for simplicity (but you can just design a different selector)

Comment: I've the code in, but I haven't gotten this to work yet. I'm very new to jquery, so I'm probably missing something obvious.

This is what my CSS looks like for search: 

#search {
 display: none;
 }

Comment: Try putting the css in the tag. Remove it from the #search rule from the css file. Your search html tag should be : <div id="search" style="display: none;"> <gcse:search></gcse:search> </div>

Comment: OK, I put the CSS inline, but nothing is happening when I click the search icon. 

Is there a specific place I need to put the callback function? I have it in the header above the nav bar:

<script>
$("#hideShowIcon").click(function() {
    $('#search').toggle();
 });
</script>

Comment: See new edit (edit 2), you need to execute your function after the document is ready

Comment: It's working now. Thanks for all of your help with this. This is my first time using jquery. Do you have any recommendations for resources on how to learn how to better use it?

Comment: Just did. You were very helpful. I'm new to this site, so it took me a little bit to figure out the difference between up voting and selecting an answer as the right one.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a non-jQuery solution:

```
document.getElementById("identifier").style.setProperty("visibility", "hidden");
```

and

```
document.getElementById("identifier").style.setProperty("visibility", "visible");
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you don't want to use the jQuery accordion effect, but using jQuery to animate the opacity?. Please see below.

```
$("#idClicked").click(function() {
   $("#searchBox").fadeTo("fast", 1);
});
```